# Не понимаю как происходит разработка библиотеки на GitHub

Tags: android, git

Есть библиотека (кастомный `View`) на гитхабе, две папки, `app`, в которой тестовый проект и `library`, в которой сама библиотека. Папка `library` устроена так:

```
library
└── src
    └── main
        ├── java
        │   └── CustomView.java
        └── res
            └── layout
                └── somelayout.xml
```

- Как мне вести разработку если это не проект, а текстовые файлы?
- Как выложить библиотеку? В Jitpack.io есть инструкция в ней написано что надо сделать release на гитхаб, я его сделал, но там zip файл можно скачать и в нем все папки, а мне надо только library. Я еще не пойму что дальше делать, чтобы все смогли подключить библиотеку одной строкой в dependencies. Какая структура у библиотеки должна быть?

Comment: Чтобы кошерно вывести на экран имена и структуру файлов и папок, используйте утилиту [tree](http://mama.indstate.edu/users/ice/tree/).

Comment: `если это не проект, а текстовые файлы` – насколько я знаю, всё программирование происходит в текстовых файлах. Поясните пожалуйста, что вы понимаете под проектом?

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, да, я запутался :( Текстовые файлы можно скопировать из проекта тогда. Вот второй вопрос - я с ним с утра мучаюсь. Думал все легко

Comment: Посмотрите на любую популярную библиотеку для андроида. Попробуйте её добавить через jitpack в свой проект.

Comment: вы имеете ввиду, что текстовые файлы на сервере github и как их изменять? Есть такая "система контроля версий" - VCS, подключаете ее в IDE в которой разрабатываете проект, когда что то изменяете в проекте, делаете push на сервер и проект будет синхронизирован. так же есть ветки master (релизная версия), develop (текущая разработка) и тп. Почитайте про систему git и как с ее помощью ведут проекты, тема очень объемная.

Comment: @pavlofff похоже, что автор уже немного освоил гит: https://github.com/ATumbler/VerticalHorizontalScrollView/commits/master. Мне кажется, вопрос в том, как правильно выделить из проекта целиком отдельную библиотеку, и потом как ее правильно выложить.

Comment: @Nick Volynkin, я все сделал, как в экзампле джитпака, тест снес, ток либу оставил, но что дальше? Релиз делать? А тогда что потом? Все? Кстати, насчет коммитов - я не могу придумать им имена XD

Comment: в коммент пишите коротко, какие изменения вносит коммит. Коммиты лучше делать атомарные, исправляющие одну проблему, добавляющие одну функцию и тд., чтобы откат не был болью.

Comment: Мне кажется, что изначально стоило библиотеку (кастомный View) разрабатывать в отдельном проекте, выложив его на GitHub. А потом просто через Jitpack добавить ее в основной проект. Насколько я понял, это уже донесли.

Comment: @ahgpoug, да, я уже оставил только библиотеку

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Заводите учетную запись в https://github.com/join
2. Берете в зубы Android Studio
3. Идете *File -> Settings -> Version Controll -> GitHub* и заводите туда свой логин и пароль полученный в github
4. Стиснув зубы разрабатываете свой виджет
5. Когда почувствуете, что код хотя бы компилируется, идете *VCS->Import into Version Control -> Share Project on GitHub*
6. Выскочит диалог с вопросом *commit all*, говорите *yes*

А вообще почитайте общие FAQ к github и git.

Comment: Это не то. Я знаю как коммитить, я не знаю как сделать библиотеку доступной для подключения всеми. И еще какая структура должна быть у нее. Вообще даже не знаю, это jar или что будет?

Comment: Дык дорогой, вопрос неверно сформулирован. Надо спросить как выложить бинарники либы в репозиторий, например в *bintray*

Answer (score 1):

Создать библиотеку можно так:

1. В вашем проекте создаете новый модуль (File -> New Module)
2. Выбираете Android Library или Java Library (ниже различия)
3. Пишите в созданном модуле то, что хотите сделать библиотекой и заливаете изменения на github
4. Открываете [Jitpack](https://jitpack.io/) и вводите в строку адрес на github вашего проекта. Jitpack выдаст вам строки, по которым можно будет добавить вашу библиотеку в проект.

**Android Library** содержит в себе зависимости от Android SDK. Упаковывается в `aar` архив, в котором могут быть помимо class файлов также и `AndroidManifest`  и ссылки на разные ресурсы(`strings, dimens, drawables`).

**Java Library** - это jar архив и несет в себе только class файлы, без классов из Android SDK

Comment: А что в файлах писать? В build.gradle?

Comment: Я сделал как вы написали, но библиотека не добавляется по строчке в build.gradle. загрузка слетает. Почему?

Comment: Не очень понимаю о чем вы. Jitpack вам выдал две строки?

Comment: Да, я все сделал, но при загрузке не качает, сбрасывает